# jq : parents with non-empty child arrays

Tags: jq, zendesk-api

I'm working with the zendesk API and the attachments are an array under comments -- effectively:

```
[
  "comments[].attachments[].content_type",
  "comments[].attachments[].content_url",
  "comments[].attachments[].file_name",
  "comments[].attachments[].height",
  "comments[].attachments[].id",
  "comments[].attachments[].mapped_content_url",
  "comments[].attachments[].size",
  "comments[].attachments[].thumbnails[].content_type",
  "comments[].attachments[].thumbnails[].content_url",
  "comments[].attachments[].thumbnails[].file_name",
  "comments[].attachments[].thumbnails[].height",
  "comments[].attachments[].thumbnails[].id",
  "comments[].attachments[].thumbnails[].mapped_content_url",
  "comments[].attachments[].thumbnails[].size",
  "comments[].attachments[].thumbnails[].url",
  "comments[].attachments[].thumbnails[].width",
  "comments[].attachments[].url",
  "comments[].attachments[].width",
  "comments[].audit_id",
  "comments[].author_id",
  "comments[].body",
  "comments[].created_at",
  "comments[].html_body",
  "comments[].id",
  "comments[].metadata.system.client",
  "comments[].metadata.system.ip_address",
  "comments[].metadata.system.latitude",
  "comments[].metadata.system.location",
  "comments[].metadata.system.longitude",
  "comments[].plain_body",
  "comments[].public",
  "comments[].type",
  "comments[].via.channel",
  "comments[].via.source.to.address",
  "comments[].via.source.to.name",
  "count"
]
```

I'm trying to select comments where the attachments are not empty.

I can select `jq '.comments[].attachments[]'`, which effectively returns the correct number of attachments, but since it's possible to upload with the same name, I need the parent created_at for disambiguation.

If I use :

```
jq '.comments[] | select(.attachments[] > 0) | {id: .attachments[].id, date: .created_at, name: .attachments[].file_name, url: .attachments[].content_url, size: .attachments[].size}'
```

This appears to append attachments to every comment.

How do you effectively select the parent only when the child array is empty?

Comment: Your input data is valid JSON but just an array of strings, while your `jq ` filter tries to access objects with fields.

Comment: I corrected the mapping above. 

While the desired fields are correct, `{}` is effectively adding new objects to each `.comment[]`

Comment: For reference:
https://developer.zendesk.com/api-reference/ticketing/tickets/ticket_comments/

Comment: If I use: 
`jq 'select( .comments[].attachments[] != [] )'` 
I still end up with .comments with empty attachment arrays: 
`"attachments": [],`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way in which you've asked the question is very confusing to most of us, but if I understand things correctly, this will help:

```
.comments[]
| .created_at as $date
| .attachments[]
| {id, $date, name: .file_name, url: .content_url, size}
```

Notice the use of some small jq clevernesses, e.g. `{id}` for `{"id": .id}`
and `{$date}` for `{"date": $date}`.

Comment: Perfect. 
Thanks for the shortcuts too, very helpful.
I didn't recognize you could call out the non empty array this way, but it makes sense.